# How can I assign a forced build to a particular build slave?

Tags: buildbot

I have a builder to which several build slaves are assigned since the machines are roughly homogeneous.  I have a force scheduler setup on this builder as well.  Sometimes, I would like to force the build to run on a particular build slave.  Is this possible?

E.g., can I use the name and value fields of the force build form on the builder's status page?

Comment: Have you tried writing [nextWorker](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-builders.html) function for builder (nextSlave in 0.8)? I think you can write functor that will select builder based on build request properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `BuildSlaveChoiceParameter()` in your force build scheduler inside of master.cfg.

Below is an example from the docs at http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.12/manual/cfg-schedulers.html#buildslavechoiceparameter

```
from buildbot.plugins import util

# schedulers:
ForceScheduler(
    # ...
    properties=[
        BuildslaveChoiceParameter(),
    ]
)

# builders:
BuilderConfig(
    # ...
    canStartBuild=util.enforceChosenSlave,
)
```

This gives you a pulldown on the web interface which has the slaves assigned to this scheduler as choices.

Comment: Very nice. That would be perfect if it works as you say. I'll accept once I'm able to test it out. Thanks!

Comment: Works as advertised. I would just add that it's also necessary to do: `from buildbot.schedulers.forcesched import BuildslaveChoiceParameter` if you're not importing everything from forcesched already.